# Checking duplicate values from database using textbox

Tags: c#, mysql, database

```
con.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from onetap.profiler where idnum = '" + txtID.Text + "'", con);
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

int i = Convert.ToInt32(result);

if (i > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Already Exist");
}
else
{
  `enter code here`
}
```

And I get this error message:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Did you debug your code? What value you are getting in `result` ? In your code `result` is not assigned anywhere?

Comment: [**SQL Injection alert**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking you're getting this error because result is null or not anything that can be interpreted as a number

Your code has other issues that need resolving though:

- it doesn't use parameters in the query - see http://Bobby-tables.com
- you don't need to download all the data to do your dupe check -

  - change your query to SELECT COUNT(*),
  - change the c# to use executescalar on the mysqlcommand object,
  - capture the result of the call into your `result` variable
- get rid of the unused MySqlDataAdapter